# How to change the editor size of CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

Since it is a textarea , I tried cols="50" in html attribute but it does not work.

Also , I found the answer from the previous question . He said I can do this by adding.
    `CKEDITOR.instances.myinstance.resize(1000, 900);` However ,  the size still has not changed.

Here is the code I attempted, thank you.

**Updated**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../plugin/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../plugin/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../plugin/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
$("#addlist").validate();
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
var div = document.getElementById('editor');
editor.resize($(div).width(),'900');
}); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="confirm.php">
        <p><br />
        <div id="editor">
            <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">
            </div>
            <? if (isset($_GET['file']))
            {$filepath=$_GET['file']; 
                require_once("../template/".$filepath);}?> </textarea>
        </p>
        </br>
            File Name </br>
            <b>(Naming Without .html e.g. MyTemplate1) :</b>
            </br>
            <input id="tname" name="tname" class="required" />

            <input type="submit" />

        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try following

To achieve this, use the [resize](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#resize) function to define the dimensions of the editor interface, assigning the window a width and height value in pixels or CSS-accepted units.

```
// Set editor width to 100% and height to 350px.
editor.resize( '100%', '350' )
```

While setting the height value, use the isContentHeight parameter to decide whether the value applies to the whole editor interface or just the editing area.

```
// The height value now applies to the editing area.
editor.resize( '100%', '350', true )
```

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Editor_Size_On_The_Fly

Comment: thanks. but what file exactly i have to modify? would you mind explain it?

Comment: Thx again, is it necessary to have a outter before i can change the size?

Comment: but when i remove the outter, it does not work , just as the jsfiddle i created. Also, since i just would like to change the size, why it does not work using editor1.resize( '100%', '450', true )? thanks

Comment: you provided jsfiddle not work either, please check it (or is chrome problem?)

Comment: In my case i don't let the user to input the height, when i modify my code by following your idea,  but it does not work. I have update the question,are there any error in my code? thank you

Comment: var div = document.getElementById('outer'); change the id outer to editor

Comment: I have changed it but still not work, please have a look on the updated question, it nearly work just need little change i think

Comment: <div id="editor">
            <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1">
            </div>, is this correct?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps i do not get it , as i have changed that already but it not works, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Just go to ckeditor folder and find config.js

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
    // config.language = 'fr';
    // config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
     config.height = '80vh';

};
```

This will resize your ckeditor based on screen size.

Answer (score 14):

For CKEditor 4.0, I had to use:

```
  CKEDITOR.replace('body', {height: 500});
```

Comment: Resize function does still exist in 4.x version, see http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-resize. So Blaze-Core's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9990208/2049986) does work for 4.x version as well.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Thank you

Comment: This works fine, i do get a warning that it is deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

//This would help.It just works for me.

```
<script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
                uiColor: '#14B8C4',
                toolbar: [
                    [ 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Link', 'Unlink' ],
                    [ 'FontSize', 'TextColor', 'BGColor' ]
                ],
                width:['250px']

            });

</script>
```

Comment: some explanation about your answer would help us understand it.

Comment: Finally someone who gave a sensible answer. Nothing else worked but this. Well there may have been others, but they were too hacky for me to want to try. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 5):

I used this solution (CKeditor4):

`.cke_contents { height: 100% !important; }`

[source](https://drupal.org/node/1012050)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 5):

```
Yes this worked perfectly We have to use config to override the styles



    <textarea  rows="1000" id="editor1" name="newsletter"></textarea>
    <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
    CKEDITOR.config.width="100%";
    CKEDITOR.config.height="700px"
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a jQuery function that uses the cols= attribute to resize the ckeditor height (scalar of 20px per row)

```
(function($) {
jQuery.fn.cke_resize = function() {
   return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var rows = $this.attr('rows');
      var height = rows * 20;
      $this.next("div.cke").find(".cke_contents").css("height", height);
   });
};
})(jQuery);

CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceReady', function(){
  $("textarea.ckeditor").cke_resize();
})
```

then your html like this will automatically resize

```
<textarea name="body" class="ckeditor" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

in ckeditor version 4.5.5

can force change height by use

---

> CKEDITOR.config.height = '800px';

---

Comment: Config options did not seem to work for me (although cannot explain why - which is bugging me) but this worked perfectly just after CKEDITOR.replace call.

Answer (score 3):

To set height of the CKEditor at the time of initialization you can follow the listed procedure.

```
<script>
       CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{
          height:['500px']
       });
</script>
```

Comment: WOW, CKEDITOR docs make no mention this is the way for v4.6. Thank YOU!

Answer (score 2):

I struggled to use resize method in version 4.3.4.

I did a hack and used below css :-

```
.cke_reset {width:807px !important; }
```

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Use `config` for updating the styles

```
editor.config.width="100%";
editor.config.height="100px"
```

Comment: Yes this worked thats
 <textarea  rows="1000" id="editor1" name="news"></textarea>
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
CKEDITOR.config.width="100%";
CKEDITOR.config.height="700px"

Answer (score 2):

CkEditor For Resize:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('OnThisDateIwillLook',
{
    toolbar: [['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],],
    skin: 'v2',               
    extraPlugins: 'autogrow',
    autoGrow_minHeight: 250,
    //autoGrow_maxHeight: auto,
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following script code to resize the height on once editor initialised.

```
<script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
        .then( editor => {
            editor.editing.view.change( writer => {
                writer.setStyle( 'height', '200px', editor.editing.view.document.getRoot() );
            } );
        } )
        .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
        } );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in other answers the resize() function is what must be used. For those who are wondering how this code can be used `editor.resize( '100%', '350' )` see below.

Suppose you create an editor for a textarea with name attribute test. Then you can call the resize() function on the instance of the CKEditor like this:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.test.resize( '100%', '80');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CKEDITOR.config.width="80%";
CKEDITOR.config.height="500px"
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering this because it took me forever to figure out how to solve this using jquery. This is similar to some answers above, but contains the instance creation to be thorough.

In my opinion, this is not elegant, and I have no idea why CKeditor doesn't inherent it's size from it's parent container, which would be much more desirable.

```
 var new_editor = $('#selected_textarea').ckeditor(function(){ 
      var set_editor_height = $('#parent_container').height()
      $('.cke_contents').css({ 'height': set_editor_height });
     });
```

This *should* work for class selectors, not just by ID.

Answer (score 0):

Using `jQuery` `ckeditor`, the only way it would finally listen to me was using a bit of a hack:

```
    $('.ckeditor textarea').ckeditor(function () {
        editor = $('.ckeditor textarea').ckeditorGet();
        $('.cke_inner').css({ 'width': '802px' });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
editor.resize('100%', '350');
editor.resize('550', '350');
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is perfectly worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('article-ckeditor',
    {
    height: '800px',
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need 100% height for your editor;

```
setInterval(function(){ 
      $('#cke_1_contents').css('height', $('#parent_div_id').outerHeight());
}, 700);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, define text area.

```
<textarea type="text" name="title" id="textEditor" required></textarea>
```

and then in script tag initialize ck editor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('textEditor',
    {
       height: '800px'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By following the instruction [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/ui/theme-customization.html), I could change almost everything I wanted to change.
I was working on a react project and I added the variables in my global.css file, then I changed its values and I added an **!important** tag(Don't forget this part) to each new variable.

These are all its colors variables, it was enough for me:

```
:root {
    --ck-color-base-foreground:                                 hsl(0, 0%, 98%);
    --ck-color-base-background:                                 hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --ck-color-base-border:                                     hsl(0, 0%, 77%);
    --ck-color-base-action:                                     hsl(104, 44%, 48%);
    --ck-color-base-focus:                                      hsl(209, 92%, 70%);
    --ck-color-base-text:                                       hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
    --ck-color-base-active:                                     hsl(208, 88%, 52%);
    --ck-color-base-active-focus:                               hsl(208, 88%, 47%);
    --ck-color-base-error:                                      hsl(15, 100%, 43%);

    /* -- Generic colors ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

    --ck-color-focus-border-coordinates:                        208, 79%, 51%;
    --ck-color-focus-border:                                    hsl(var(--ck-color-focus-border-coordinates));
    --ck-color-focus-outer-shadow:                              hsl(207, 89%, 86%);
    --ck-color-focus-disabled-shadow:                           hsla(209, 90%, 72%,.3);
    --ck-color-focus-error-shadow:                              hsla(9,100%,56%,.3);
    --ck-color-text:                                            var(--ck-color-base-text);
    --ck-color-shadow-drop:                                     hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.15);
    --ck-color-shadow-drop-active:                              hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.2);
    --ck-color-shadow-inner:                                    hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);

    /* -- Buttons ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    --ck-color-button-default-background:                       transparent;
    --ck-color-button-default-hover-background:                 hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
    --ck-color-button-default-active-background:                hsl(0, 0%, 85%);
    --ck-color-button-default-active-shadow:                    hsl(0, 0%, 75%);
    --ck-color-button-default-disabled-background:              transparent;

    --ck-color-button-on-background:                            hsl(0, 0%, 87%);
    --ck-color-button-on-hover-background:                      hsl(0, 0%, 77%);
    --ck-color-button-on-active-background:                     hsl(0, 0%, 73%);
    --ck-color-button-on-active-shadow:                         hsl(0, 0%, 63%);
    --ck-color-button-on-disabled-background:                   hsl(0, 0%, 87%);

    --ck-color-button-action-background:                        var(--ck-color-base-action);
    --ck-color-button-action-hover-background:                  hsl(104, 44%, 43%);
    --ck-color-button-action-active-background:                 hsl(104, 44%, 41%);
    --ck-color-button-action-active-shadow:                     hsl(104, 44%, 36%);
    --ck-color-button-action-disabled-background:               hsl(104, 44%, 58%);
    --ck-color-button-action-text:                              var(--ck-color-base-background);

    --ck-color-button-save:                                     hsl(120, 100%, 27%);
    --ck-color-button-cancel:                                   hsl(15, 100%, 43%);

    --ck-color-switch-button-off-background:                    hsl(0, 0%, 69%);
    --ck-color-switch-button-off-hover-background:              hsl(0, 0%, 64%);
    --ck-color-switch-button-on-background:                     var(--ck-color-button-action-background);
    --ck-color-switch-button-on-hover-background:               hsl(104, 44%, 43%);
    --ck-color-switch-button-inner-background:                  var(--ck-color-base-background);
    --ck-color-switch-button-inner-shadow:                      hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.1);

    /* -- Dropdown ------------------------------------------------------------------------------ */

    --ck-color-dropdown-panel-background:                       var(--ck-color-base-background);
    --ck-color-dropdown-panel-border:                           var(--ck-color-base-border);

    /* -- Input --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    --ck-color-input-background:                                var(--ck-color-base-background);
    --ck-color-input-border:                                    hsl(0, 0%, 78%);
    --ck-color-input-error-border:                              var(--ck-color-base-error);
    --ck-color-input-text:                                      var(--ck-color-base-text);
    --ck-color-input-disabled-background:                       hsl(0, 0%, 95%);
    --ck-color-input-disabled-border:                           hsl(0, 0%, 78%);
    --ck-color-input-disabled-text:                             hsl(0, 0%, 46%);

    /* -- List ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    --ck-color-list-background:                                 var(--ck-color-base-background);
    --ck-color-list-button-hover-background:                    var(--ck-color-button-default-hover-background);
    --ck-color-list-button-on-background:                       var(--ck-color-base-active);
    --ck-color-list-button-on-background-focus:                 var(--ck-color-base-active-focus);
    --ck-color-list-button-on-text:                             var(--ck-color-base-background);

    /* -- Panel --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    --ck-color-panel-background:                                var(--ck-color-base-background);
    --ck-color-panel-border:                                    var(--ck-color-base-border);

    /* -- Toolbar ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    --ck-color-toolbar-background:                              var(--ck-color-base-foreground);
    --ck-color-toolbar-border:                                  var(--ck-color-base-border);

    /* -- Tooltip ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    --ck-color-tooltip-background:                              var(--ck-color-base-text);
    --ck-color-tooltip-text:                                    var(--ck-color-base-background);

    /* -- Engine -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    --ck-color-engine-placeholder-text:                         hsl(0, 0%, 44%);

    /* -- Upload -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    --ck-color-upload-bar-background:                           hsl(209, 92%, 70%);

    /* -- Link -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    --ck-color-link-default:                                    hsl(240, 100%, 47%);
    --ck-color-link-selected-background:                        hsla(201, 100%, 56%, 0.1);
    --ck-color-link-fake-selection:                             hsla(201, 100%, 56%, 0.3);
}
```